# Can't collect data from database the correct way

Tags: php, android

I have the function `getDistance()`. The function `findDistance()` inside the while loop, calculates the distance between 2 users, by using coordinates (latitude-longitude), and returns to var `$djson` the distance in meters. `$distance` is a string committed by the user for first time and `$user_old["distance"]` is a string which is called from a database in `$query`. I wanted to be able in `$matched_names`, to save all the names of the users from my database, for who the condition inside `if()` is true, regarding the sum of the distance of the new user who commits his data  and the old ones inside the database. The problem is that `$matched_names` saves the first name which is called from the database and for as many times the loop goes on without even considering the `if()` restriction. For example if the first name called in `$user` is "Mike", and `$user` has 5 rows then the output will be: `Mike,Mike,Mike,Mike,Mike`.

I suppose that i have made some mistake in the way things work inside while..

```
<?php
public function getDistance($uuid, $name, $distance, $latstart, $lonstart, $latend, $lonend, $gcm_regId) {

    $query = sprintf("SELECT uid, gcm_regid, name, distance,latstart, lonstart, latend, lonend  FROM user_demand WHERE latstart='%s' AND lonstart='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($latstart),
    mysql_real_escape_string($lonstart));
    $user = mysql_query($query);

    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($user);
    $user_old = mysql_fetch_assoc($user);

    while( $user_old = mysql_fetch_assoc($user)) {
        $djson = $this->findDistance($latend,$lonend,$user_old["latend"],$user_old["lonend"] );
        if ($user_old["distance"] + $distance >= $djson) {
            $match = $this ->df->addUserMatch($user_old['gcm_regid'],$user_old['name'],$gcm_regId,$name);
            $matched_names = array_fill(0,$no_of_rows,$user_old['name']);   
            $matched_gcmz = array_fill(0,$no_of_rows,$user_old['gcm_regid']); 
        }
    }

    $registatoin_ids = array($gcm_regId);

    $message = array("names" =>$matched_names,"gcm" => $matched_gcmz);
    $result = $this ->gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i usually do is, when I'm going to write something that is complicated, is to get it to working without being in a function then break it down into functions. 
It is less confusing and easier to troubleshoot problems that way.

It is kind of hard to tell what it is doing since you didn't post your other function and the if statement relies on the output of that function.

Offhand, it could be this line where you are using the $name and $user_old['name']

$match = $this ->df->addUserMatch($user_old['gcm_regid'],$user_old['name'],$gcm_regId,$name);

I think you would want it to match each other. Like if $name = $user_old['name'] then add it, if not, do something else.